# webscraping - get the first and the second value from the div tag with multiple values seperated by coma

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a tag which looks like this

```
<div class="small text-gray mb-2">
    <div>
        Pierre M
        <!-- -->
        , 
        <!-- -->
        08/18/2018
        <!-- --> 
        <div class="d-inline-block px-0_25 text-white bg-primary-darker rounded">
            updated 
            <!-- -->
            03/11/2021
        </div>
      </div>
       <div>Long Range 4dr Sedan (electric DD)</div>
</div>
```

I would like to get only the name and surname so the "Pierre M" and the date "08/18/2018"

I was trying this code

```
import bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup()
data = []

for e in content_list:
    data.append({
        'reviewer-name':e.select_one('div').text,
        'reviewe-date':e.select_one('div').text,
    })
```

But it results in taking every value from that tag so I get

```
'reviewe-date': 'John Schreiber, 10/06/2018 updated 10/08/2019Long Range 4dr Sedan (electric DD)',
'reviewer-name': 'John Schreiber, 10/06/2018 updated 10/08/2019Long Range 4dr Sedan (electric DD)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with `find_all(text=True, recursive=False)` to get only the first section of text in your specific case:

```
for e in soup.select('div.small'):
    data.append({
        'reviewer-name':''.join(e.div.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).split(',')[0].strip(),
        'reviewe-date':''.join(e.div.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).split(',')[-1].strip(),
    })
```

Alternativ would be to check for child `<div>` with updated, save its text if needed and `decompose()` it from the `DOM` -
*use of `walrus operator` needs `python` 3.8 or later else use standard `if statement`)*:

```
for e in soup.select('div.small'):
    if (u := e.select_one('div.rounded')):
        updated = u.text.split('updated')[-1].strip()
        u.decompose()
    else: 
        updated = None
    data.append({
        'reviewer-name':e.div.text.split(',')[0].strip(),
        'reviewe-date':e.div.text.split(',')[-1].strip(),
        'reviewe-updated':updated
    })
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<div class="small text-gray mb-2">
    <div>
        Pierre M
        <!-- -->
        , 
        <!-- -->
        08/18/2018
        <!-- --> 
        <div class="d-inline-block px-0_25 text-white bg-primary-darker rounded">
            updated 
            <!-- -->
            03/11/2021
        </div>
      </div>
       <div>Long Range 4dr Sedan (electric DD)</div>
</div>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
data = []

for e in soup.select('div.small'):
    if (u := e.select_one('div.rounded')):
        updated = u.text.split('updated')[-1].strip()
        u.decompose()
    else: 
        updated = None
    data.append({
        'reviewer-name':e.div.text.split(',')[0].strip(),
        'reviewe-date':e.div.text.split(',')[-1].strip(),
        'reviewe-updated':updated
    })

data
```

###### Output

```
[{'reviewer-name': 'Pierre M', 'reviewe-date': '08/18/2018', 'reviewe-updated': '03/11/2021'}]
```

Comment: now it says that u is not defined, could you help me?

Comment: Plus for the review_date I get: 06/29/2018 updated 07/02/2019Long Range 4dr Sedan (electric DD) instead of just the first date

Comment: walrus operator is an python 3.8 or later feature but you can also use a standard if statement `if e.select_one('div.rounded'):         updated = e.select_one('div.rounded').text.split('updated')[-1].strip()         e.select_one('div.rounded').decompose()`

Answer (score 3):

I have done this solution with your example html in my local with regex:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
with open("C:/Users/yas/Desktop/salah.txt", "r") as My_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(My_file, 'html.parser')
    e = soup.select_one('div').text.strip()
    exp = re.split("\n",e)
    buyer_name=exp[0]
    buyer_date = exp[4]
    print(buyer_name,buyer_date)
```

you can use any form of regex and its methods in your code with any loops for your database :)